# Does any DisplayPort->HDMI adapter support 1920x1080@75Hz, or do I need to look for something specific?

Tags: hdmi, displayport, adapter, refresh-rate

School's coming and I bought a used PC for my first grader, since there's a good chance there will be remote studying later. Too late however did I realize that it only has DisplayPort outputs.

I could now get it a monitor that supports DP, but those are much rarer than those that support HDMI. And all other monitors in my home are DVI/HDMI, so if there ever was an emergency and I needed to attach a different monitor to the computer, I'd be out of luck.

So I thought it would be better to get a regular HDMI monitor and a DP->HDMI adapter. Those adapters are cheap, after all. I found [a good monitor that I like](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/UM.WS0EE.A01) and then started looking for an adapter, but then ran into something confusing. The monitor supports both 60Hz and 75Hz refresh rates, and [reportedly it looks better at 75Hz too](https://www.techspot.com/review/1981-acer-sb220q-amazon-most-wanted/), so obviously I want to run it at 75Hz. But when I look at the adapters, they all say "up to 1920x1080@60Hz"

I looked at [Display port Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits) and according to that, even the lowest levels of DP spec support 1920x1080@75Hz. But does a 5-10€ adapter respect the specs? Should I perhaps look for a 4K adapters, just to be on the safe side?

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Display Port is the most modern standard there is. Many displays already support DP along with other inputs and it is likely that it may be the standard one day. HDMI is going to be the limiting factor here as it may bottleneck what the cable/converter can do. In all cases it will not be due to DisplayPort.

Comment: @LPChip - Quite possible, but it's not The Standard yet. HDMI is still holding on strong. At any rate, I have no doubt that DP itself is more than capable of 1920x1080@75Hz, but are the adapters?

Comment: I would choose DP over anything anytime. I personally would rather buy a new monitor that supports DP than to do HDMI and run into all kinds of compatibility issues. If the adapters support it, its hit and miss really. The DP side will support it, but its up to the HDMI side to support it too, given that there are old and new HDMI specs. So look for what version of HDMI that converter is rated.

Comment: @LPChip I didn't think HDMI was that much of a mess. TBH, so far I've never seen any issues with it at all. Maybe I've gotten lucky?

Comment: Maybe. Its mostly that old HDMI standards are more limited, probably not doing the 75Hz that you are interested in but only 60Hz, which is the main point of concern here. I don't doubt any HDMI to DP will be a problem, except for this refreshrate thingy. Displays, especially TV's didn't go beyond 60Hz for a long time and HDMI also exists for a long time. (and yes, I know many TV's claim to be 100hz or more) but they still transmit 60hz signal and apply some filtering to make it look like 100hz.

Comment: @LPChip - umm.... I'm pretty sure I've done 75Hz through DVI/HDMI many times. In fact, the monitor I've linked only has a HDMI input and it can do 75Hz.

Comment: Yeah, but HDMI 1.0 can't do 75hz, pretty sure. If you get a cheap HDMI to DP, you may get unlucky and find one that doesn't do 75hz. Just trying to save you a lot of trouble by pointing you to the weakest link.

Answer (score 1):

So after doing a little poking around, it doesn't look like most DP to HDMI adapters support 75Hz, but there are a few that do.

This one does and has been verified by at least 2 people: [https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-DisplayPort-Supports-Displays-3840x2160/dp/B01GW8DZV4/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GW8DZV4)

Comment: I ordered one that also claims to be 4K compatible, so will see.